# How to get a private URL for a document through search API?

Tags: box-api

When receiving search results from the Search API, I get back a bunch of file IDs. I'd like to display these results to a user as links to the original documents. Is there any way to convert these IDs into canonical *private* URLs? Either the v1 or v2 APIs are fine for this purpose.

Thanks.

Edit: By private URL, I meant a URL that the owner of the document can access.

Answer (score 2):

You can use V2 http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-create-a-shared-link-for-a-file and use "access":"Collaborators".   If it is a private folder, with no collaborators, and you do not add anyone else to the list of collaborators, then the owner will be the only person that can use that "shared link."  Quotes added because the word share then becomes rather ironic, as you're not sharing with anyone really.

You can add someone else into a collaboration and thus into the club of people allowed to use that shared link by doing a curl call like this:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/collaborations \
-H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN" \
-d '{"item": { "id": "FOLDER_ID", "type": "folder"}, {"accessible_by": { "id": "USER_ID"}, "role": "editor"}' \
-X POST
```

That is also documented in the V2 API at http://developers.box.com/docs/#collaborations-add-a-collaboration

The subtlety is that collaborators are added at the folder level, but shared-links are created at the file level.  I suppose you could be asking us for a new shared-link level "owners" which would only allow owners access to the shared link for the file.   That doesn't exist at the moment.

Comment: I don't want to add a collaborator. I want to provide a link for the *owner* of the document to be able to view.

Comment: Is this *really* the only way to get a URL for the owner of the document?

Comment: Why can't boxhq just support a unique or time-expired url like *every other service*, including your competitor dropbox, and amazon s3?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach here would be to setup your application to proxy the download.  Create a call in your application which uses the [Box "Download a file" API Call](http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-download-a-file) and in turn streams the response from that call back to the user through your web server.  This is often not trivial to setup, and there's various gotchas involved (for example what happens if the download call fails).

Depending on the language, framework, and web server you are using this can be harder or easier to accomplish.  In some cases it can be fairly straightforward.

Comment: We're returning search results. Downloading the document isn't as useful as simply linking to it.